# Save ImageView to Android Emulator Gallery

Tags: android, file-io, io, android-imageview, android-gallery

I'd like to Save an Image to the Android Gallery, here's my current code:

```
image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

image.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = image.getDrawingCache();

if(!new File("/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).exists())
    Log.e("Error","/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+" Dont exist");

File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/myImage.jpg");
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
ostream.close();
Toast.makeText(Ads.this, "Offer saved", 1).show();
```

It always returns the same error:

```
Error: /Pictures Dont exist
```

Then an IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This is on a 4.0 Android Virtual Device.
I've tried to use `Environment.getRootDirectory()` to get the root directory of the AVD also, but I still receive the same errors.

What is the correct way to test saving an image to gallery in an AVD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, you already have the `Bitmap` you can use this code to insert it into the gallery:

```
Bitmap b = image.getDrawingCache();
Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, title, description);
```

`title` and `description` can be null if you don't care about setting them. If the `Uri` returned is non-null, then the insertion was successful.

Comment: Every tutorial I have seen about saving images to the Gallery never mentioned this method! Damn, it was so easy all along! Thanks.