# Having trouble saving image to gallery in Android

Tags: java, android, http

I'm writing an Android app and I'm trying to save the image to the phone's image gallery.  When I step through this code it seems to be running fine and no exceptions are thrown.  I simply don't see the downloaded images in my gallery and I can't find them on my emulator.

**Why won't the images downloaded with the code below show up in my phone's gallery?**

```
URL imageURL = new URL(photoRequestUrl);
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openStream());

//getContext().
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContext().getContentResolver(), imageBitmap, "title" , "description");
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10362422/1777090). Its slightly changed than your method. Check if works.

Comment: Have you included `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you reboot your phone will see the picture in the gallery. Try to write this line after writing some into storage.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```